# Matrix equation notation

Tags: matrices, notation

I have been reading through a paper and saw a notation that i did not know about. It says that we have to solve the matrix equation $\Delta \mathrm{h}'=\mathrm{Lh}'$. That it clear to me, but what does the following mean:
[Image of equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEct2.png).

I was not able to find any information on what that means. Can anybody tell man or atleast give me some keywords to help me.

Comment: Depends on the context.  Need more information, e.g., which paper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will start with the left-most matrix, as I think this is what you will be struggling the most. This defines a $(k-b+1)\times k$ matrix. It means that the first $k$ rows and $k$ columns of the matrix consist of the $k\times k$ matrix $L$. Then, below this, we have an identity matrix in the bottom right corner, of size $(k-b+1)\times (k-b+1)$ Then, the gaps on the left hand side are filled by zeros.

This may be better explained by example. Let's take $k=5$ and $b=3$ and let
$$
L=\begin{pmatrix}
1&3&2&1&8\\
9&7&0&1&3\\
2&3&1&1&4\\
7&0&1&3&10\\
8&1&9&3&2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Then the matrix described by your picture is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&3&2&1&8\\
9&7&0&1&3\\
2&3&1&1&4\\
7&0&1&3&10\\
8&1&9&3&2\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If, instead, we let $b=2$ then we would obtain the following matrix.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&3&2&1&8\\
9&7&0&1&3\\
2&3&1&1&4\\
7&0&1&3&10\\
8&1&9&3&2\\
0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then, according to your picture, we are multiplying this matrix by another matrix $h'$ and obtaining another matrix consisting of $(\Delta h)'$ at the top and 0's underneath (to make up the required dimension of the matrix).